# What do the bars between keyframes mean?

Tags: animation

Between some keyframes a bar is drawn, when is a bar displayed?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This means that the keyframes which the bar connects are the same.

From the [manual](http://115.28.130.42/blender/editors/dope_sheet/introduction.html):

> When the value of a given channel does not change at all between two neighboring keyframes, a gray (unselected) or yellow (selected) line is drawn between them.

E.g. If you insert a `LocRot` keyframe on frame `1`, then rotate and insert another `LocRot` keyframe on frame `10`, the `Location` will not have changed so there will be a bar drawn between each location channel keyframe:

[image]

[image]