# Dope sheet editor. What does the orange line between keyframes mean?

Tags: keyframes, dopesheet

I start to use the dope sheet view to see my key frames. But I don't understand why for some I have an orange line and not for others like below. What is the meaning of the orange line between keyframe?

[image]

Comment: See: [make a keyframe last longer than one frame](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12297/make-a-keyframe-last-longer-than-one-frame/12302#12302)

Answer (score 4):

Those orange lines represent a hold: the selected keyframes at each end have the same value, so there is no transformation in between them.

For example:

[image]

For unselected keyframes the line connecting equal keyframes will be displayed in gray.